Finished Installation - Only boots to UEFI instead of OS - Says "no bootable devices found"
I bypassed the problems I posted about on this post by simply choosing only the most bare-bones installation options (Default Selection, no third party add-ons), and it worked, up until the point where it asked me to reset my PC and remove the boot-drive, as when I did, it booted to UEFI.
I'm not sure what could cause this, but I'm going to read some older posts here and see what they did, and I'll keep my old post up for anyone with similar problems...
EDIT 1:
I'm attempting to Install Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, written to USB Drive (with more than enough storage space) via BalenaEtcher, as per the official installation guide.
PC Hardware:
Motherboard: GIGABYTE B650 Gaming X
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 7700x (8 core/16 thread)
RAM: G.skill Ripjaws S5 (32GB x2)
Storage: TEAMGROUP Vulcan Z 2TB SSD
GPU: AMD Radeon RX 6750 XT
Sound card: Sound BlasterX AE-5 Plus
EDIT 2: After taking my PC to a professional, it turns out the issues were caused by several minor hardware errors I made during assembly culminating together

You've given no clues as to what Ubuntu product & release you attempted to install, nor if you performed any checks (found in the documentation) you performed were tried. A You've not given any clues as to what installer was used (that varies on release & especially product), how you wrote the ISO to media (if written in a format incorrect for your hardware boot loader issues can be the result - which is what you describe! or did you write ISO as per documentation for you unstated product/release) etc.   I'd check your ISO & media write firstly, but provide full details for us to help.

How are the partitions mounted? Are they mounted as a RAID array? Append to your question the output of 'mount'
